# Return Unique Rows from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Here is my procedure and this return multiple rows because Feature ID has multiple id for one vendor id how to modified it so that it returns unique rows kindly help me out.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetVendorsPageWise
 @PageIndex INT = 1
      ,@PageSize INT = 10
      ,@type nvarchar(max)
      ,@city nvarchar(max)
      ,@query nvarchar(max)
      ,@RecordCount INT OUTPUT
      AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
            order by Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID asc
      )AS RowNumber
      ,Unit_Table.Unit_title, Vendor_Base_Price.Base_Price, Vendor_Base_Price.showprice, Category_Table.Title, Vendor_Registration.Business_Name, 
                         Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Street_Address, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Locality, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Nearest_Landmark, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.City, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.State, 
                         Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Country, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.PostalCode, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Latitude, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Longitude, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.ImageUrl, 
                         Vendor_PrimaryInfo.ContactNo, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Email,Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID,Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID,Vendor_Value_Table.Value_Text

     INTO #Results
      FROM  Unit_Table INNER JOIN
                         Vendor_Base_Price ON Unit_Table.Unit_ID = Vendor_Base_Price.Unit_ID INNER JOIN
                         Vendor_PrimaryInfo ON Vendor_Base_Price.Vendor_ID = Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID INNER JOIN
                         Vendor_Registration ON Vendor_Base_Price.Vendor_ID = Vendor_Registration.Vendor_ID AND 
                         Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID = Vendor_Registration.Vendor_ID INNER JOIN
                         Category_Table ON Vendor_Registration.Category_ID = Category_Table.Category_ID
                         LEFT JOIN
                         Vendor_Value_Table ON Vendor_Registration.Vendor_ID = Vendor_Value_Table.Vendor_ID LEFT JOIN
                         Feature_Table ON Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID = Feature_Table.Feature_ID
                         where Vendor_Registration.Category_ID=@type and Vendor_PrimaryInfo.City=@city + @query
                          order by Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID


      SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
      FROM #Results

      SELECT * FROM #Results
      WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

      DROP TABLE #Results
      END
```

[This is result set with duplicate items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9Y4A.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for editing marc_s i m newbie here.

Comment: Why not just remove the FeatureID from your select? If that isn't what you need, can you please show what your results look like currently and what your desired results should look like.

Comment: But i want Feature_ID to be there

Comment: Then we need to see current results and expected output to clarify what you need.

Comment: How i insert image here of my result?

Comment: click "edit" at the bottom left of your post. Ideally we need it in plaintext, not an image.

Comment: @scsimon yup i added image

Comment: This isn't all of your results, since it ends at Street_Address. Do you need the rownumber? If not, don't select * from #results... select specific columns

Comment: there is a lot result i m explaining you,you can see there are same address there all have different feature id that are inserted in another table so when i fetch the results this returns multiple rows i think u might get now i just want to get 1 row thats why i use rownumber here but stuck here

Comment: bottom line is you can use DISTINCT to get unique rows but as long as you keep selecting RowNumber you aren't going to limit your results. You are assigning a RowNumber to every single row in your results. You aren't partitioning or limiting on any in your ROWNUMBER() windows function.

Comment: How would i use distinct if i had different feature_id also?

Answer (score 0):

You will use the `DISTINCT` keyword

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
  FROM #Results
WHERE 
  RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 
  AND
  (((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1
```